# Удаляется media notification при запуске WebView

Tags: android, android-notification, android-webview

В приложении есть три активити под каждую задачу. У каждой активити несколько фрагментов. Одна из активити отвечает за радиоплеер. Плеером можно управлять как из фрагметов приложения, так и через media notification в "шторке". За всё это отвечает сервис. И всё работает как положено - при закрытии приложения, при ползании в приложении по другим фрагментам\активити.

За одним исключением - фрамент webview  в котором я открываю сайт chatovod. При этом радио продолжает играть без проблем, то есть сервис работает, исчезает именно notification. При этом другие notification этого же приложения (например от активити с картинками) никуда не деваются.

Пробовал создавать для webview отдельную активити. ПРобовал открывать не chatovod а гугл - всё равно просто удаляет media notfication и всё. При этом, когда на радио начинается новый трек, то notification появляется (у меня реализован в сервисе функционал его перерисовки при смене трека) и никуда не девается. И если после этого выйти с webview, а потом вернуться, то оно не исчезает. Но если полазать, попереключать станции, то после нескольких переключений, повторный заход в webview снова удаляет media notification =)

Ниже код webview, код сервиса очень большой, если надо могу скинуть куда-нибудь в другое место.

```
class ChatovodFragment: Fragment() {

private lateinit var webView: WebView

companion object {
    fun newInstance(url: String): ChatovodFragment {
        val fragment = ChatovodFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_CHATOVOD_URL, url)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack()
            } else {
                activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    })
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chatovod, container, false)
    val url: String =
        if (arguments != null) {
            requireArguments().getString(BUNDLE_CHATOVOD_URL, "")
        } else
            ""
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
    return view
}

class MyWebViewClient: WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
        return true
    }
}
```